# Laravel, массив в formData. При указании метода через _method пропадает элемент массива

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Необходимо реализовать добавление и изменение массива через ajax. Бэкенд на laravel6.

Отправляю массив через FormData как свойство images.

При явном указании метода через _method = PUT (при _method = POST тоже самое) пропадает элемент массива.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На бэке получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый элемент массива всегда не доходит до бэка при указании метода через _method.

Jquery ajax запрос с:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

С чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Comment: Код формы добавьте, либо смотрите существующие примеры типа https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-multiple-files-images-upload/#viewfile

Comment: Код контроллера в студию)

Comment: Код контроллера? dd($request); сразу при срабатывании метода